# Creating a C++ wrapper for gsl_vector* that plays nicely with GSL's root finding tools (e.g. gsl_multiroot_function_fdf)

Tags: c++, wrapper, smart-pointers, gsl, raii

Broadly speaking, I'm looking for the best way to deal with legacy functions `f(T*)` that are called internally when replacing T* with a smart wrapper. In my case, `T` is `gsl_vector`, and I'm creating a class `Vector` that stores a `gsl_vector*`. This class functions both as a wrapper, implementing overloaded numeric operators, and also as a smart pointer, dealing with the resource allocation and deallocation of the `gsl_vector*` pointers. However, I run into a slight problem when using gsl's numerical root finding tools. This procedure requires that I create an object `gsl_multiroot_function_fdf`, which is a struct containing function pointers such as

```
int (* fdf) (const gsl_vector * x, void * params, gsl_vector * f, gsl_matrix * J)
```

This function pointer is called within GSL's internal algorithms, so I have no control over the `gsl_vector*` and `gsl_matrix*` passed in, and in particular I don't own them. I do have complete control over the functions that these function pointers reference, and I would like to take advantage of my `Vector` (and `Matrix`) wrappers, since I have a lot of computation to do that the wrappers simplify. The simplest thing to do is to create new `Vector` and `Matrix` objects and copy their data to `f` and `J`, but all this copying is unnecessary and slow. Better would be to wrap `f` and `J` and directly modify them. With the simple implementations of the wrappers I have now, if create a wrapper around either of these pointers, however, their memory will be deallocated when the wrappers go out of scope.

Is there an accepted best practice for what to do in this case, where I wish I could completely enforce RAII encapsulation of all `gsl_vector*` and `gsl_matrix*` data but can't because of legacy code? My solution now is to have a typical false boolean `softwrap` in my `Vector` and `Matrix` classes, and a named constructor

```
static Vector SoftWrap(gsl_vector* v);
```

that creates a `Vector` with `softwrap=true`. When this boolean is true, the memory isn't deallocated in the destructor. This approach seems to work, but perhaps it's silly in some way that I haven't foreseen.

A separate but possibly related issue is how to deal with `const gsl_vector*` objects. There are separate stackoverflow questions dealing with this already (suggestions: a `ConstVector` class, templates, etc.).

Comment: Thinking about it I can't see a better way of doing this. As you are forced to use raw pointers you are always going to have to in some way  tell your `Vector` class that it doesn't own the pointer is being passed to it and therefore shouldn't deallocate when it is destructed.

Comment: OK; the more I've thought about the more this has seemed like the best solution, but of course that could be from my own lack of imagination so I'm glad that you see see it the same way. (And you make the case pretty strongly that this is the *only* way, whereas I was wondering if some combination of references and std::moves/std::forwards could work magic). I think I could use the same technique for dealing with the `const gsl_vector*`, something like `static const Vector ConstVector(const gsl_vector* x)` that uses `const_cast<gsl_vector*>(x)` ...

Comment: You could create a wrapper where Vector is a child class - derived from gsl_vector. In that case, you can pass gsl_vector to the routine and you will have a reasonable control over the resources

Comment: @ViniciusMiranda While a good idea in general, in this case I believe your solution is impossible, since gsl_vector is a struct, not a class.

Comment: @jwinberley - structs and classes are basically the same in C++ - the only difference is that the default access in a class is private while the default access in struct is public